# Describing Frequency & Period with zoo

Tags: r, frequency, zoo

I have weekly sales observations for several products. I then create a zoo object to hold these data but can't make the frequency/cycle work as I intend. Data is available at [Dropbox (asr.csv)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78vxae5ic8tnutf/asr.csv).

I've been able to create a ts that respects the frequency and period, but I've struggled to make it work well with my (gap-filled) weekly observations.

Probably also worth noting, I'm actually drawing my data from an ODBC connection (using CSV to assist here).

How do I correctly describe this data when creating the zoo?

```
> sales <- read.csv("asr.csv")
> library(zoo)

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:base’:

as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> sales.zoo <- zoo(subset(sales, select=c(2:length(sales))), order.by=sales$date_end, frequency = 52)
> sales.zoo.i <- na.approx(sales.zoo) # interpolate internal NA values
> frequency(sales.zoo.i) # 52, which seems right
[1] 52
> cycle(sales.zoo.i[1:20,10]) # everything is in the one cycle...
2004-08-14 2004-08-21 2004-08-28 2004-09-04 2004-09-11 2004-09-18 2004-09-25 
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1 
2004-10-02 2004-10-09 2004-10-16 2004-10-23 2004-10-30 2004-11-06 2004-11-13 
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1 
2004-11-20 2004-11-27 2004-12-04 2004-12-11 2004-12-18 2004-12-25 
         1          1          1          1          1          1 
>
```

Comment: can you say what do you expect to have for **cycle**? Also , what do you mean by correctly describe the data?

Comment: If I understand the nomenclature used by R (and I very possibly don't), the cycle would be the position of the observation within each period. For weekly observations and a yearly period, this should give a cycle like 1,2,...,51,52,1,2,...,51,52,etc. By "describe", I mean how do I describe the frequency, period, deltat in such a way that the zoo can be used to identify seasonality.